# 500 Server Error on Django Website - ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am uploading a Django website to an Apache 2.4 server on Ubuntu 16.04. My server is running mod_wsgi. I am getting an ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi. I have read through many other solutions, but none seem to work. I am thinking that my error has something to do with my Python installation (Python 2.7), but I am not sure. My `wsgi.py`, server conf, and error messages from the Apache logs are below:

Apache Error Log:

```
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.891778 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 27832:tid 140404955539200] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 134.53.122.114:63670] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://173.255.204.6/
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.891833 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 27832:tid 140404955539200] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 134.53.122.114:63670] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://173.255.204.6/
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.891884 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 27832:tid 140404955539200] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 134.53.122.114:63670] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://173.255.204.6/
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.891891 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 27832:tid 140404955539200] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 134.53.122.114:63670] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://173.255.204.6/
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892105 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921] mod_wsgi (pid=27831, process='site', application='site.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/site/site/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892490 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921] mod_wsgi (pid=27831): Target WSGI script '/var/www/site/site/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892504 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921] mod_wsgi (pid=27831): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/site/site/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892532 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892564 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921]   File "/var/www/site/site/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892611 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Apr 13 15:51:06.892647 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 27831:tid 140404925069056] [remote 134.53.122.114:11921] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

wsgy.py:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/site')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias www.site.com
        ServerAdmin admin@site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site

        WSGIDaemonProcess site python-path=/usr/bin/python
        WSGIProcessGroup site

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site/site/wsgi.py process-group=site

        <Directory /var/www/site/site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>

        Alias /media/ /var/www/site/media/
        Alias /static/ /var/www/site/static/

        <Directory /var/www/site/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/site/media>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type `which python` to find where Python is installed, the result is `/usr/bin/python`

When I try to visit my IP Address in the browser, I receive a 500 Server Error with the admin email provided in the Apache Conf, so I know this file is being used.

When I disable my `wsgi.py` file through my Apache Conf and visit my IP Address, there is a webpage for me to navigate the files I have in my `/var/www/` folder.

When I test `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application` in the Python console, it works fine.

I am not using virtualenv.

Is there any other way for me to debug this, or has anyone found a solution to this error?

Comment: @Thameem I still get a server error when I do this with the same output in the error logs.

Comment: WSGIDaemonProcess site python-path=/usr/bin/python

try something instead of this

WSGIDaemonProcess site  python-path=/var/www/site/site  python-home=/usr/bin/python

Comment: @Thameem I tried those and received the same error. Do you know if there is any way I can get a more detailed error message?

Comment: @Thameem I am here. I also disabled WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup and I get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142554/discussion-between-kevin-and-thameem).

Comment: @Thameem I have installed virtualenv and Django.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your wsgi.py file to set the sys.path to include the parent directory that contains your novabucket module, probably like this:

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/maxmackie/webapps/django/novabucket')
More information is available in our documentation: Adding to sys.path within Python and WSGI Scripts

Be sure to restart your Apache after making these changes. .